# Tiny URL creator

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, url, hashcode

**Coding challenge:**

> Convert a given long URL into a Tiny URL. The length of this Tiny URL
>   should be fixed and the same for all URLs. You should return the full
>   URL if given a shortened URL.

I am aware this code is technically flawed as there will be clashes owing to the limitations of the `hash` function in Python.

Therefore I am not specifically looking for coding suggestions on this specific library. Instead what I am curious to know is if this can be improved to use an even shorter URL extension (e.g: 6 characters) that is unique.

I considered using a different hashing function from the `import hashing` library but the output of these are usually 32-64 characters long and therefore certainly not a "Tiny" URL.

```
class TinyURL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.storedURLS = {}

    def encode(self, long):
        tiny = hex(hash(long))
        self.storedURLS[tiny] = long
        return tiny

    def decode(self, tiny):
        if tiny in self.storedURLS:
            return self.storedURLS[tiny]
        else:
            return "Tiny URL is not in the database"

t = TinyURL()
encoded = t.encode("google.com")
print(encoded)
decoded = t.decode(encoded)
print(decoded)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to cut down on the number of characters that you need to guarantee a certain amount of robustness, it would be wise to pick a greater pool of characters to choose from. At the moment you are basically left with 16 valid values (0, 1, ..., 9, A, ..., F). Case does not count here since `0xA` is equal to `0xa`. For 6 characters that leaves you with \$16^6=2^{24}\$ possible short-urls.

If you were to encode them using the [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) alphabet, you would have 64 characters to choose from, which grants you \$64^6=2^{36}\$ possible short-urls.

```py
import base64

desired_length = 6
encoded_hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
    str(hash("www.google.com")).encode("ascii")
)
minified_address = encoded_hash[:desired_length]
```

A character of a base64 string will represent 6bit instead of 4bit as a hex value does. As a consequence you would need to pick a length that is a multiple of two if you ever wanted to revert the encoded bytes, but that should not be necessary in your case. Take note that I opted for the url-safe version of the base64 alphabet which replaces `/` by `_` and `+` by `-`.

---

It might also be worth to think about using a "stable" hash function, e.g. from [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) or one of the general purpose hash functions presented [here on this site](http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/), instead of the built-in `hash(...)` which uses a random seed to [mitigate certain attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522708) (also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) in the documentation of `object.__hash__`). But that depends on whether you want to map `www.google.com` to the same short-url every time your program is queried or not.

Comment: Is there not a risk that ```encoded_hash[:desired_length]``` would cause a clash as the first 6 characters may be the same but the last characters may be different?

Comment: Of course there is a risk. But the risk is also present if you just use a shorter hash. A hash of a given bit-length \$n\$ can only represent \$2^n\$ values without collision. If you were to encode them in hex and pick 6 characters you end up with \$n=24\$ (\$n=36\$ for base64).

Answer (score 6):

I know this isn't really what you're asking for, but I have a couple suggestions about how the code is setup and written.

Coming from languages that use `long` as a type, a line like:

```
self.storedURLS[tiny] = long
```

Is a little jarring initially. No, `long` is not a type or builtin in Python, but I think it would be neater if a more descriptive name was used, and one that doesn't clash with other languages. I'd probably write it closer to

```
class TinyURL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.storedURLS = {}

    def encode(self, full_address):
        minified_address = hex(hash(full_address))
        self.storedURLS[minified_address] = full_address

        return minified_address

    def decode(self, minified_address):
        if minified_address in self.storedURLS:
            return self.storedURLS[minified_address]
        else:
            return "Tiny URL is not in the database"
```

---

I also disagree with a String message being returned in the result of a lookup failure in `decode`. What if the caller wants to check for failure? They'd have to check the return against a known error message, which is clunky.

I'd return `None` in the event of failure, then document that fact.

```
def decode(self, minified_address):
    """Returns the full address associated with the given minified address,
        or None in the event of an invalid minified_address.
    """
    return self.storedURLS.get(minified_address, None) # None is the default
```

That way, you can easily handle a failed lookup:

```
t = TinyURL()

full_address = t.decode("bad address")

if full_address:
    print("valid")

else:
    print("invalid")
```

And I *think* with the new assignment expression, you'll be able to write that even more succinctly:

```
if full_address := t.decode("bad address"):
    print("valid", full_address)

else:
    print("invalid")
```

Although apparently 3.8 isn't released yet? I think the above should work, although I don't think I can test it quite yet.

Comment: Thanks. I remember ```long``` being a builtin method in Visual Basic 6 (years and years ago!). I take your point though. Thanks

Comment: @EML Really, it's not a big deal, I just personally don't like the look of it. I switch back and forth between languages a fair amount, and that line gave me a short "they're assigning a type?" moment. I wouldn't be surprised if other Java/C++ writers feel similarly (although I'm curious if that's the case).

Answer (score 5):

While I agree with [the other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223461/98493) that you should not return a special string denoting failure, in Python you should refrain from returning *any* special return value (though if you do, `None` is an OK choice).

Instead you usually want to raise an informative exception, which can then be handled by the caller. Here the code already raises a `KeyError`, which you could keep, or you could add a custom exception.

```
def decode(self, tiny_url):
    """Returns the full address associated with the given tiny url.
    Raises a `KeyError` in the event of an invalid `tiny_url`. """
    return self.urls[tiny_url]

...

try:
    decoded = t.decode(encoded)
except KeyError:
    print("Invalid")
print(decoded)
```

Note that I also changed the name of `TinyURL.storedURLS` in order to conform to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using `lower_case` as variable and function names.